# my app stops working on pos device

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using an android POS mini device on which I have installed my android app which uses google play services. I also have installed play services version 11.7.44 and play store version 8.4.40 by myself. Because it doesn't provide this 2 apps by default.

In my project I use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'
```

And also services.

Sometimes my app stops working and doesn't even throw any error. Every time I have to reset my pos device to get over this error. I tried by clearing cache and other stuff as well. Is there any option to get rid off from such things?

In my minipos device its return null the session after some transation so how can i sloved it.

Comment: Does the POS device have telephone support or is it WiFi only

Comment: my POS device have wifi only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google won't allow Google Play services on Google Play on a device which is not Android Compatible and passed the compatibility test suite (CTS). ([source](https://source.android.com/compatibility/)).

Self-installing Play services and Play might not be the cause, it might be a symptom of a device which is not truly Android compatible. Can you provide more details of your device in the question?

Any Android device which stops an app you would expect to provide errors in the log. This is also a sign the device is not fully android compatible.

I'd suggest testing your app in the emulator (which does allow Google Play services) and configure the emulator to be as close as possible to your device. That at least will give a stack trace if your app crashes, and allow you to debug.

There is an app on Google Play called [SafetyNet Helper Sample](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scottyab.safetynet.sample). This will connect to a Google service called [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html) and tell you if the manufacter has passed CTS tests for the device. If they manufacturer hasn't then they aren't allowed to describe the device as "Android Compatible" ([source](https://source.android.com/compatibility/)), even if it is based on the Android source code which is open source.

Comment: my device name is MiniPOS, model no : rK3188 and version of my device is 4.4.2 and my miniPOS device is android compatible.

Comment: RK3188 is not a model number, it is a CPU / SoC. I'll expand the answer to explain how you can check CTS compatibility

Comment: i have downloaded SafetyNet Helper Sample app which shows the error message in red screen like CTS Profile match = false , Basic Integrity = false, note = The basic integrity field is a weaker check than ctsProfileMatch. for result from ctsProfleMatch.then how can i sloved it

Comment: You can't solve it, this is telling you the POS device you are using has not been officially tested as Android compatible. The only way to fix it is switch to a different POS device (one which is CTS tested) or ask the manufacturer of this device to certify their device. Until people like you start putting pressures on manufacturers, such devices won't become reliable and well tested.